# associate array values for check-box name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a check box like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="grp_user_ids[]" id="grp_user_ids_" value="2" class="selectit">
```

(I am iterating this check box for users in my table consider 3 users so 3 check boxes)

using Jquery i collected all the user_id's now i want to relate or assign the array  to the name attribute  `grp_user_ids[]`.
when the form gets submitted I would like to receive the parameters like 
`grp_user_ids["3","2","1"]`
my jquery array is: `["3","2","1"]`

How to append the array to this name attribute?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try `$('form').serialize();`

Comment: This type of name, i guess it automatically groups in an array as you defined it. Did you tried with form submission?

Comment: Just submit the form. Server side form handler libraries almost always have built in methods to treat identically named inputs as arrays of data. There's no need to involve JavaScript.

Comment: You dont have to collect the values and assign it if it is inside the `form` tags. Just use `$('form').serialize()` and submit the form.

Comment: use this pen sorry for the fiddle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGjobZ am creating an array like : var grp_users = []; var user_id = $(this).attr('userid'); grp_users.push(user_id); either way on selecting from left to right or right to left i will have the array with user id and on form submit i need to have the format like tha